# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry crc-32 (expected 0x3950d9fc but got 0x12b44089)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, junit, build.gradle

When I used studio Android to create a project to report this exception, I do not know where there is a mistake, but he can run successfully, build will appear this error, turn to attack first thank you!

**error message:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry crc-32 (expected 0x3950d9fc but got 0x12b44089)
```

**build.gradle:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fomove.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

**screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0`

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 25` and `targetSdkVersion 25` . then clean-rebuild-gradle

Comment: I don't have the configuration you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question for the wrong reason is that SDK-23 is damaged and then I have to download it again to solve the hope that can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Make a full clean of the Project! That **will** help!
I can help if you dont know how to gradle:clean

Comment: I have used Build - project >clean but it will still be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to FREE some space from in the Drive where Android Studio Installed.

This may also cause if your drive is full For example you Installed Android Studio in C Drive, If C Drive is Full you may see this ERROR, Try to FREE some space

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error on a API 19 KitKat project I was starting.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding but no success but what worked for me was going to File/project structure/ app/ flavors and changed the build to another version only briefly. I then changed back into API 19 KitKat and clicked OK. This rebuilt the project and the app worked. May be a possible solution for some.